# Single-row subquery returns more than one row BUT with one row

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, average, window-functions

"CityJail" schema. I am supposed to find each appeal that has a less than the average number of days between the filing and hearing dates.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT appeal_ID
FROM appeals
WHERE (hearing_date - filing_date) <
(SELECT AVG(hearing_date - filing_date)
FROM appeals
GROUP BY appeal_ID)
GROUP BY appeal_ID;
```

I get an error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
> 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Finding the average works fine by itself:

```
SELECT AVG(hearing_date - filing_date) "Average"
FROM appeals;
```

> 2810.666666666666666666666666666666666667

So I am thinking: it doesn't like my "GROUP BY" and so I start commenting them out one by one:

```
SELECT appeal_ID
FROM appeals
WHERE (hearing_date - filing_date) <
(SELECT AVG(hearing_date - filing_date)
FROM appeals;
--GROUP BY appeal_ID)
--GROUP BY appeal_ID;
```

And now I am getting the error:

> ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
> 00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
> *Cause:
> *Action:
> Error at Line: 4 Column: 2

The appeals table:

```
Name         Null?    Type      
------------ -------- --------- 
APPEAL_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER(5) 
CRIME_ID     NOT NULL NUMBER(9) 
FILING_DATE           DATE      
HEARING_DATE          DATE      
STATUS                CHAR(1)
```

Comment: In your last query you've commented out a close bracket, and included a `;` where the close bracket should go.  Adopting a clearer layout and indentation would make that easier to spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need any `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT appeal_ID
FROM appeals
WHERE hearing_date - filing_date < (SELECT AVG(hearing_date - filing_date) FROM appeals)
```

The subquery computes the average difference between the two dates over the whole table - don't use a `GROUP BY` clause here, otherwise it will return multiple rows, and generate that error. The outer query likely does not need aggregation either.

You could also express this with window functions:

```
select *
from (select a.*, avg(hearing_date - filing_date) over() avg_diff from appeals a) a
where hearing_date - filing_date < avg_diff
```

Comment: I swear I tried to comment them out one by one. I don't know how I missed that.